# Let $Y=1/X$. Find the pdf $f_Y(y)$ for $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $X$ have pdf

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}  & 0<x<1 \\
\frac{3}{8}  & 3<x<5 \\
0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

(a) Find the cumulative distribution function of $X.$

(b) Let $Y=1/X$. Find the pdf $f_Y(y)$ for $Y$. Hint: Consider three cases: $1/5 \le y \le 1/3, 1/3 \le y \le 1,$ and $ y \ge 1.$

**Where I Am:**

I think I did part (a) correctly. I did the following:

$$F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}x +c_1  & 0<x<1 \\
\frac{3}{8}x + c_2  & 3<x<5 \\
0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$F(0)=0=\frac{1}{4}(0)+c_1 \implies c_1 = 0 $$
$$F(5)=1=\frac{3}{8}(5)+c_2 \implies c_2 = -\frac{7}{8} $$

Therefore:

$$F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}x   & 0<x<1 \\
\frac{1}{4}    & 1<x<3 \\
\frac{3}{8}x - \frac{7}{8}  & 3<x<5 \\
1            & x > 5
\end{cases}$$

If that's not right, however, please let me know.

Now, for part (b), I got a little lost. Here's what I did:

$$ \text{Let } g(x) = \frac{1}{x} \implies g'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} $$

Then:

$$ f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(x)}{\lvert g'(x) \rvert} = \frac{f_X(\frac{1}{y})}{\lvert g'(\frac{1}{y})\rvert} $$

Therefore:

$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}  & 0<\frac{1}{y}<1 \\
\frac{3}{8}  & 3<\frac{1}{y}<5 \\
0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and taking reciprocals and flipping inequalities...

$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}  & y \ge 1 \\
\frac{3}{8}  & \frac{1}{5} \le y \le \frac{1}{3} \\
0            & \frac{1}{3} \le y \le 1
\end{cases}$$

This, however... doesn't seem right. For example, what is $f_Y(y)$ when $y \in [0, \frac{1}{5}]$? Is it just $0$? I know I did something wrong here, but I can't quite figure out what exactly. If anybody could help me out, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT:** "Second" Attempt...

$$F_X \left( \frac{1}{y} \right) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{1}{y} \right)   & y \ge 1 \\
\frac{1}{4}    & \frac{1}{3} \le y \le 1 \\
\frac{3}{8}\left( \frac{1}{y} \right) - \frac{7}{8}  & \frac{1}{5} \le y  \le \frac{1}{3} \\
0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore:

$$ f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X \left( \frac{1}{y} \right)= \begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{1}{y^2} \right)   & y \ge 1 \\
-\frac{3}{8}\left( \frac{1}{y^2} \right)  & \frac{1}{5} \le y  \le \frac{1}{3} \\
0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: For a start, check the CDF of X:  for example, $F_X(2) = ?$ and $F_X(7) = ?$Remember that the CDF is nondecreasing.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's $0$. The CDF definitely can't be discontinuous like that. I'll work on that. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the PDF of Y is constant only over the intervals where it is 0. Think carefully about what intervals for Y inherit probability from X. Maybe for a preliminary problem, consider $V \sim Unif(0,1)$ and $W = 1/V$.

Comment: Well, $W$ should have the pdf of $\frac{1}{w^2}$ because it's just the inverse uniform distribution.

Comment: No. $F_W(w) = P(W \le w) = P(1/V \le w) =\dots= 1-1/w,$ for $w > 1.$ Careful. You seem to have unresolved misconceptions.

Comment: Definitely $F_Y(y)$ is not piecewise constant.  See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You recall correctly that $ f_Y(y)=f_X(x)/\lvert g'(x) \rvert = f_X(1/y)/\lvert g'(1/y)\rvert $ but then you apply $ f_Y(y)= f_X(1/y)$, why is that?

Comment: Good question. Just an oversight, I guess. But, now that I think about it, I'm not even sure what to do with that because $f_Y(y)$ would become $(1/y)(1/y^{-2})$ which is just $y$. So, that makes even less sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Crude sketch of CDF of Y based on a simulation. Perhaps helpful as a check on your work.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Well, qualitatively, the function appears to be $0$ for $y < 1/5$, some linear function of $y$ for $1/5 < y < 1/3$, some constant function (around, say, $3/4$) for $1/3 < y < 1$, and then some sort of logarithmic function for $ y > 1$. It appears that I was way off...

Comment: Semi-nasty problem. Go step by step, not backwards from this graph.

Comment: This may be the CDF, but the PDF was what the question called for.

Comment: @MichaelHardy; Right, intended as encouragement to get PDF via CDF. Trying lead to answ without giving it. Works sometimes, sometimes not. Your approach successful.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}  & 0<x<1 \\
\frac{3}{8}  & 3<x<5 \\
0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac d {dy} F_Y(y) = \frac d {dy} \Pr(Y\le y) = \frac d {dy} \Pr\left( \frac 1 X \le y \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac d {dy} \Pr\left( X\ge \frac 1 y \right) \text{ (if }y>0) \\[10pt]
& = \frac d {dy} F_X\left(\frac 1 y \right).
\end{align}
Now notice that when $3<x<5$ then $\dfrac 1 5 <\dfrac 1 x < \dfrac 1 3$, or $\dfrac 1 5 < y < \dfrac 1 3$ and similarly for other intervals.

In part $(a)$ I'd use definite integrals.  Since $f_X(x)=0$ when $x<0$, you have for $x\ge 0$,
$$
F_X(x) = \int_0^x f_X(w) \, dw.
$$
If $x>1$, this becomes
$$
F_X(x) = \int_0^x f_X(w) \, dw = \int_0^1 f_X(w)\,dw + \int_1^x f_X(w)\,dw
$$
and if $x>3$ then
$$
F_X(x) = \int_0^x f_X(w) \, dw = \int_0^1 f_X(w)\,dw + \int_1^3 f_X(w)\,dw + \int_3^x f_X(w)\,dw.
$$

Comment: So, for part (a), that's what I tried at first, but: The first interval is given by the integral $\int_{0}^x \frac{1}{4}dt$ giving $\frac{1}{4}x$. The second interval is given by $\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{4}dt +\int_{1}^x \frac{1}{4}dt$ giving $\frac{1}{4}x$, as well. But, shouldn't this be simply $\frac{1}{4}$ because the pdf is $0$ there, so the CDF doesn't "pick up" any more probability? And then the third interval is given by $\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{4}dt + \int_{1}^3 \frac{1}{4}dt + \int_{3}^x \frac{3}{8}dt$ which gives $\frac{3}{8}(x-1)$ which, evaluated at $x=5$ doesn't equal $1$, as it should.

Comment: Your definition said "$0$ otherwise".  That would mean the density is $0$ between $1$ and $3$, so if $x$ is between $1$ and $3$, then you'd have $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac 1 4 \, dt + \int_1^x 0\,dt$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Right. But, then, in consideration of that, the CDF becomes what I have up in the OP.

Comment: Which, actually, shouldn't be a CDF because it decreases around $x=3$. Sigh...

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude : It is the _density_ that decreases.  The CDF for values of $x>3$ but $<5$ would be $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac 1 4 \, dt + \int_1^3 0\,dt + \int_3^x \frac 3 8\, dt $.  No decreasing is happening. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hmm. I'm confused. If you plot $F_X(x)$ and look at it around $x=3$ it jumps down from $F(x) = 1/4$ to $F(x)=-33/32$ as it moves from one interval of the function to the next. Am I taking crazy pills, or something?

Comment: It doesn't jump downward anywhere.  How did you conclude that anything like that happens? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It was definitely the result of spending too much time thinking about this problem. I was plugging in the wrong values. Long day. Sorry about that!

Comment: Ok. I've included my latest attempt in the OP, if you have any interest in looking at it.